# Eclipse RCP Application crashes after long hours of inactivity, why?

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

I am not able to figure out the solution for this problem, after long hours of inactivity, if i click or just restore the tab of the application that i am building, i get an exception saying "org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles". Why do i get this ? I am beginner in SWT.

Comment: With so little information we can only guess - you probably aren't calling `dispose` on your resources (things like `Color`, `Font`, `GC`, `Image`, .... must all be disposed when no longer needed).

Comment: Showing us the full stack trace for the error would also help.

Comment: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawBitmapAlpha(GC.java:1222)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawBitmap(GC.java:1180)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(GC.java:1005)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(GC.java:900)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.wmDrawChild(Label.java:678)

Comment: @greg-449 please read above

Comment: This still looks like you aren't disposing of things.

Comment: Yes I am, but how do i decide when to dispose what ?